# Getting "EIdHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST'" exception

Tags: ssl, twilio, c++builder, indy, vcl

I am working on a VCL application and I have to integrate Twilio using its REST API:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/your-request-to-twilio

Here is my code:

```cpp
pair<bool, String> SMSTwilio::SendMessage(TComponent* Owner,
    String ToNumber, String FromNumber, String Message)
{
    if(Message.Length() > MESSAGE_LIMIT) {
        ShowMessage("Message must have " + IntToStr(MESSAGE_LIMIT) +
            " or fewer characters. Cannot send message with " +
            IntToStr(Message.Length()) + "characters.");
    }

    AccountSID = "AC2d48*****************0deb52";
    AuthToken = "9e28ec***************c0126e";
    Message = "Hi";
    FromNumber = "+1740****95";
    ToNumber = "+9*****791";

    String URI = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"
        + AccountSID +
        "/Messages";

    TStringList* params = new TStringList();
    params->Add("From=" + FromNumber);
    params->Add("To=" + ToNumber);
    params->Add("Body=" + Message);

    TIdHTTP* HTTP = new TIdHTTP(Owner);
    HTTP->Request->Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    HTTP->Request->ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    HTTP->Request->BasicAuthentication = true;
    HTTP->Request->Username = AccountSID;
    HTTP->Request->Password = AuthToken;

    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL* Handler = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(Owner);
    Handler->SSLOptions->Method = sslvTLSv1;
    HTTP->IOHandler = Handler;

    bool isSuccess = false;
    String Result = "";

    __try {
        try {
            HTTP->ReadTimeout = 5000;
            HTTP->ConnectTimeout = 5000;
            Result = HTTP->Post(URI, params);
            isSuccess = true;
        } catch(Exception &e) {
            isSuccess = false;
            Result = e.Message;
        }
    }
    __finally {
        delete HTTP;
        delete params;
    }

    return make_pair(isSuccess, Result);
}
```

I am getting an `EIdHTTPProtocolException` with message `"HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST"` thrown by `Result = HTTP->Post(URI, params);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You are posting to the wrong URL.

You are posting to `.../Messages` but you need to post to `.../Messages.json` instead (notice the `.json` at the end), per Twilio's [Message Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message) documentation:

> Create a Message resource
>
> **POST** `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Messages.json`
>
> To send a new outgoing message, make an HTTP POST to **this Messages list resource URI**.

---

Also, although not errors per-say, there are some other issues with your code:

- your `Owner` parameter is unnecessary.  Since you are creating and destroying your `TIdHTTP` object in the same function, there is no need to assign an `Owner` to it at all.  And it would be more useful to assign that `TIdHTTP` object as the Owner for the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` object, instead of some unknown external Owner.
- you are not returning an error to the caller if the `Message` is too long to send.
- you are not adequately protecting your objects from leaks if something bad happens (why not use C++ smart pointers instead of `try..finally`?).
- your `catch()` should be catching the `Exception` object by **const** reference.
- you don't need `Request->Connection = "Keep-Alive"` since you are closing the connection after the `Post()` is finished, you are not actually using a keep-alive.
- you should be using the `SSLOptions->SSLVersions` property instead of the `SSLOptions->Method` property.  That will then allow you to enable `sslvTLSv1_1` and `sslvTLSv1_2`, since many servers are phasing out TLS 1.0 nowadays, so you should prepare for that sooner rather than later.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

std::pair<bool, String> SMSTwilio::SendMessage(
    String ToNumber, String FromNumber, String Message)
{
    if (Message.Length() > MESSAGE_LIMIT) {
        String msg = Format(_D("Message must have %d or fewer characters. Cannot send message with %d characters."), ARRAYOFCONST(( MESSAGE_LIMIT, Message.Length() )) );
        //ShowMessage(msg);
        return std::make_pair(false, msg);
    }

    String AccountSID = _D("AC2d48*****************0deb52");
    String AuthToken = _D("9e28ec***************c0126e");

    //Message = _D("Hi");
    //FromNumber = _D("+1740****95");
    //ToNumber = _D("+9*****791");

    String URI = Format(_D("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%s/Messages.json"), ARRAYOFCONST(( AccountSID )) );

    std::unique_ptr<TStringList> params(new TStringList); // or std::auto_ptr prior to C++11

    params->Add(_D("From=") + FromNumber);
    params->Add(_D("To=") + ToNumber);
    params->Add(_D("Body=") + Message);

    std::unique_ptr<TIdHTTP> HTTP(new TIdHTTP(nullptr)); // or std::auto_ptr prior to C++11

    HTTP->ReadTimeout = 5000;
    HTTP->ConnectTimeout = 5000;

    //HTTP->Request->Connection = _D("Keep-Alive");
    HTTP->Request->ContentType = _D("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    HTTP->Request->BasicAuthentication = true;
    HTTP->Request->Username = AccountSID;
    HTTP->Request->Password = AuthToken;

    TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL* Handler = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(HTTP.get());
    Handler->SSLOptions->SSLVersions = TIdSSLVersions() << sslvTLSv1 << sslvTLSv1_1 << sslvTLSv1_2;
    HTTP->IOHandler = Handler;

    bool isSuccess = false;
    String Result;

    try {
        Result = HTTP->Post(URI, params);
        isSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (const Exception &e) {
        isSuccess = false;
        Result = e.Message;
    }

    return std::make_pair(isSuccess, Result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the points you have listed. They are really helpful and I have fixed them except the one i.e `Handler->SSLOptions->SSLVersions = TIdSSLVersions() << sslvTLSv1 << sslvTLSv1_1 << sslvTLSv1_2;`. I got an exception saying "`SSLVersions` is not a member of TIdSSLOptions".

Comment: I am using Indy version 10.1.5 http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/index.EN.aspx

Comment: @Monjo you are using a very outdated version and need to [upgrade](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx). The latest version is 10.6.2.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and let you know if there is any problem.